# an interest conjecture about the length of paths in a simple graph

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a simple graph and let $A$ and $B$ be two different vertices of $G$. Suppose $P$ is a path between $A$ and $B$ in $G$ which satisfies the following:

For every vertex $u$ of $P$, there exists another vertex $v$ of $P$ and a vertex $C$ of $G$ which is not on $P$ such that $u$, $C$ and $v$, $C$ are both adjacent.

Then I conjecture that there must exist another path between $A$ and $B$ in $G$ which is longer than $P$. Is this true?

Comment: Do you mean a "simple" path? I.e. without repeated vertices?

Comment: Unless G is infinite, mustn't this fail because there must be a longest path? (I appreciate there might be several paths of the same longest length, but the conjecture explicitly uses _longer_.)

Comment: @postmortes There is nothing contradictory here. The longest path won't satisfy this condition if it's true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think that your statment is true .
There exist another path from $A$ to $B$ which is shorter or in the same length.
Let's look at the path $P:A=a_1\dots u.a_n\dots v,\dots a_m=B$(without lost of generality let v be closer to B).

So if i understand the question coerrctly there exist a path $S=a_1\dots u .c.v.a_k \dots a_m$ 
so the path is shorter if u and v are not adjacent.If they are than its true.

Edit :i just so that $G $ is asimple graph and if so ' you cannot make your assumption because then you will have a loop $u.c.v.a_k \dots a_n.u $ and if you dont assume that G is simple , i can give you a counter example(i dont write it now because it's hard to write graphs in latex)

Edit:
[image: Graph G]

As you can see this graph setisfies your asumptions and the path $P=a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4$

$|P|=4$ and it is the maximal path (of course you canot repeat the same vertix)

As you can see if the path is already the maximal path it is untrue.

Edit :lock at the same graph but identify the vertexes $a_5,a_6$

Comment: Assuming G is infinite, I don't think this works.  You seem to be tacitly assuming that there's only one vertex where this works, but it's true for all of them.  So you can add a vertex, use it to jump from u to v, walk _back_ along path P to u+1 (vertex immediately after u in the original path) and then go from there to some v' elsewhere in the path.  This might well be longer than the original and isn't covered by your answer.

Comment: How do you define the longest path if $G $ is infinite, and i have edited my answer .

Comment: There isn't necessarily a longest path if G is infinite, but as was pointed out to me, the longest path doesn't meet the criteria of the hypothesis!  Looking at your edit; I thought that _loops_ that simple graphs disallowed were those that went from a vertex to itself.  I would have called what you're describing a _cycle_ and I thought they were allowed?

Comment: As i know cycles aren't allowed in a simple graph , But if they do your conjecture is still false,unfortunately i dont know how to write graph in latex but if you wish i can take a photo of a counter example

Comment: A _complete graph_ is a simple graph where every pair of vertices is connected by an edge, which necessarily permits cycles for graphs of at least four vertices.  See here: http://www.ucl.ac.uk/~ucahbtw/docs/d1lesson1/D1_graphs_glossary.pdf
for example.
If you do have a good counter-example it would be nice to see!

Comment: I have edited again

Comment: That looks good to me!  Nicely done :)

Comment: You are welcome

Comment: I don't see how this is a counter-example at all. Your graph reinforces the conjecture since $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4$ induces the longer path $a_1,a_2,a_5,a_3,a_4$.

Comment: I am sorry i will edit